# Can we be certain that Signal doesn't log metadata (e.g. message graphs)?

Tags: encryption, verifiability, signal-protocol

I know Signal uses public/private key E2E encryption to ensure it's impossible for them to read the contents of messages.  WhatsApp does too, hence Signal's main attraction is that it additionally claims to avoid collecting metadata pertaining to the messages (unlike WhatsApp).  Their server code, last time I checked, is public, so this serves to support this claim, and Signal additionally use some sort of verification system to advertise which system is running on their backend (I'm not at all knowledgeable about that system, but would assume it's vulnerable to Man-in-the-middle or other such meddling).

However, I was thinking about how Signal could actually verify their claims cryptographically, and I'm at a loss.  Surely there must be a theoretical possibility that they can log an incoming message and the outgoing destination receiving the message?  This would be enough to build valuable graphs structures of who is messaging who.

Is "no metadata collection" a claim that can actually be verified by a centralised organisation?  I can imagine a few ways of obscuring the desination of a message recipient (e.g. the way things work with TOR), but as far as I know this is far from the way Signal works.  Any insights would be much appreciated.  I tried looking up my query online, but haven't found any similar questions out there.

Comment: [Is Signal still more secure than WhatsApp?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/139493/is-signal-still-more-secure-than-whatsapp) This was the most comprehensive answer in [security.se]

Comment: You can use TOR to hide your IP from signal servers.

Comment: @kelalaka, yes TOR can be used to hide the IP address.  But this doesn't prevent Signal from logging metadata relating to who is the sender and who is the recipient.  Surely as a single organisation the sender and recipient must be theoretically transparent to them.  I can't think of how else they would ensure the sender's message arrives to the right recipient.

Comment: Well, it is a matter of trust for now, however, if all sides uses TOR, AFAIK one can be safe. Hey at least, they don't show the sign https://signal.org/blog/setback-in-the-outback/ and Actually, they mocked the Australian government, too. https://signal.org/blog/sealed-sender/

Comment: Even if all sides use TOR, that would only hide IP addresses.  Signal's centralised servers would still have some form of user ID for the sender and the recipient (without this, passing the message on to the right person would not be possible).  This alone is enough to build visual graphs of message networks, and it has previously been proven that these graphs (e.g. with bitcoin) could in theory be deanonymised with access to supplemental graph data for comparison, e.g. from the likes of social media.  Bitcoin used to be considered completely private too, but the same fault applied there.

Comment: Enable sealed sender. That is key, however, one may abuse the system. That is, you sent one message, enabling the sealed sender to get the message. Only the true recipient can decrypt, though.

Comment: Sealed sender still leaves the recipient exposed, though.  There are ways this can be leveraged by a compromised org to generate graphs of who is messaging who.  For example, the timing of messages, paired with the transparent recipient, can be used to deduce that two users with sealed sender activated are in fact conversing with each other.  This could also be done even if the recipient were hidden (tor-style), but the fact that the recipient ID is transparent makes it genuinely feasible to extrapolate message graphs.

Comment: I don't think it reveals, the signal fan-out to all enablers of seladed sender service. The response time can be exploited..

Comment: Are you sure that's how it works - i.e. all feature enabled users receiving a copy?  That sounds like it would be incredibly slow.  I'd imagine a mobile phone would explode if a bunch of signal's traffic was being redundantly fanned into it for obscurity reasons.  It works for TOR because it's decentralised and traffic can hop through a small number of nodes, but I just don't think the centralised model can guarantee metadata privacy in any form.

Comment: From others' accounts, I think what happens with the sealed sender feature is that the recipient remains transparent to Signal (https://www.reddit.com/r/signal/comments/kvz7qs/can_someone_eli5_the_sealed_sender_technology/)

In that case, a short to-and-fro message exchange between two users on a couple of occasions would be more than enough to build a message graph from the metadata.  Even if it's difficult to initially identify a user, as more users get identified via aligned timing of messages, identifying more careful users becomes easier (same way a crossword gets easier over time).